# When adding 7, 3, and 1 into a red-black tree, do I need to perform a right rotation?

Tags: algorithms

If I add the following in this order into a red-black tree:

```
tree.Put(7)
tree.Put(3)
tree.Put(1)

         7                  3
        /   rotate(3)      / \
       3    ----->        1   7
      /
     1
```

should I perform a right rotation after the insertion of `1` ?

I am reading the [algorithms bible](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) but it the pseudocode doesn't indicate what to do.

Comment: Do you understand why you might want to?

Comment: Yes because access speed degenerates to a linked list in a left-leaning tree.

Comment: Very good.  So should you perform a right rotation after the insert of 1?  I have the book you are reading, let me go get it...

Comment: I want to. But in the pseudocode, it searches for the `uncle` node of `1` (a right child of 7) but in this tree, there is no `uncle` node. Are you saying I should handle this as a corner case (even if the pseudocode does not tell me to) ?

Comment: Look at Figure 14.4, and notice how rotations occur until all nodes alternate between red and black as you traverse the tree from the root to the leaves.

Comment: @JacquesRenéMesrine I think you should consider that the root has an invisible black right child.

Comment: @Simon You are correct. I thought about this while walking home. This was actually mentioned in the MIT OCW video but I had forgotten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the root, 7 is black. After inserting the 3, it is red (because all inserted nodes are reds).

When you insert the 1, it is also red, so you have violated one property (the son of a red node must be black). Since you also need to maintain the fact that all paths have the same number of black nodes, you cannot simply color the 3 in black.

So you need to perform a rotation.

**After checking the book**: I believe this is case 3: color the grandparent red & perform right rotation.